# Problem installing RGtk2 in Arch Linux (Manjaro)

Tags: r, gtk2, pango, rgtk2

I need to install RGtk2 on mu Manjaro i3 laptop. When I install this package, I get the following error:

```
    In file included from ./RGtk2/pango.h:22,
                 from RGtk2/gtk.h:5,
                 from RGtkDataFrame.h:1,
                 from RGtkDataFrame.c:1:
./RGtk2/pangoClasses.h:7:25: error: unknown type name ‘PangoFontClass’; did you mean ‘PangoFontMapClass’? [etc]
```

I have the following packages installed:

- pango 1:1.44.3-1
- gtk2 2.24.32-1

Any suggestions on how to get RGtk2 to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stumbled upon the same issue on Fedora. The `RGtk2` package is apparently using some Pango structures that shouldn't be using in the first place. Since v1.44, these structures are explicitly private, and thus the compilation error.

I've notified both the Pango and RGtk2 maintainers. For now, the only workaround is to downgrade Pango to v1.43.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I downgraded to 1.43.0-2 using the downgrader package in Arch and presto, RGtk2 compiles.